# Headings including sections and/or subsections

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

i got a problem with my headings. This is what I defined:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,bibliography=totoc,twoside,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{scrpage2}
%\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\markright{}



\title{Bachelorthesis}
\author{Victoria ***} % Removed name
\date{August}

\begin{document}

and of course it ends with 
\end{document}
```

My problem is that i only get simple lines without the sections shown. If I use `myheadings`, than I can put stuff in, like the date... but i just want to get the section up there. I have no idea what's going wrong! 
I've also tried to use `\pagestyle{headings}` then the error `!extra\else` shows up!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This question could probably be improved by making the code a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the problem, with at least one section, and a plain text page (not a title page).

Comment: Is `\automark[subsection]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}` what you want?

Answer (score 2):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext} % jsut fot this example

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```